# Adding a datestamp in jquery

Tags: jquery, datestamp

Let's say I have the datestamp formatted like this:

```
var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

Silly question here, but bow do I display this on my page?

I tried this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    var now = new Date();
    var todayDate = dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
    $('div').html(todayDate);
}

<body onload="View();" >
    <div id="datatable" align="center"></div>
</body>
```

Here's the entire HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript"> 
        function View(){
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;        
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://someremoteserver/display_a_table.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }
     </script>
</head>

    <body onload="View();" >
        <div id="datatable" align="center"></div>

        <script language="Javascript"> 
            now = new Date();
            todayDate = dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
            document.write("Last update: ", now()); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried document.write in the body above but the syntax is wrong. Can you please correct plus show me how to change the font size?

Comment: Look at my edited code below

Answer (score 0):

Just select an area in your HTML you want it and place it in the html with the .html() tag like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var now = new Date();
        var todayDate = dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
        $('#datatable').html(todayDate);
});

    <body>
        <div id="datatable" align="center"></div>
```

**UPDATE:**
Updating your code from above.

You don't want document.write() function as that will clear the contents of the page and write what ever you give the function. So document.write('here') will be a blank page with the word "here" on it.

Also if you want to use those format time functions you are going to need to include http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js.

So basically I am keeping your code for getting the table. Then I added a div with id='timestamp' to place the time in. Then I use jQuery to take the time and place it in the timestamp div and alter it's size with `$('#timestamp').html('Last update: <span style="font-size:18px">'+todayDate+'</span>')`;`

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript"> 


$(document).ready(function(){  
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;        
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://someremoteserver/display_a_table.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(); 




            now = new Date();
            todayDate = dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
            $('#timestamp').html('Last update: <span style="font-size:18px">'+todayDate+'</span>'); 
      });
     </script>
</head>

    <body>
        <div id="datatable" align="center"></div>

        <div id="timestamp"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The $(document).ready() is jQuery that automatically runs when the page fully loads.

Comment: The above code displays the date on the page alright, but that's it. The table from responseText is not displaying.

Comment: What table? Where are you getting responseText?

Comment: There's a table I'm pulling from a remote server using responseText. I'd like to display the datestamp before or after this table.

Comment: document.write works, but what is the syntax to change the font size plus display the date?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "table" still. If you have the code in xmlhttp.responseText then you could just do $('#datatable').html(xmlhttp.responseText); 

But if you could post your whole code it would help.

Comment: And describe in as much detail what you are trying to accomplish, because I am not exactly sure what you want.

Comment: I updated my op with the entire html. All I'm trying to do is add a datestamp on top or bottom of this table I'm pulling from a remote server.

Comment: rjg132234 sorry for the delay in response, but your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you so much!